# Do mathematics teaching professional organizations publish hiring recommendations?

Tags: secondary-education, teachers

Suppose that a secondary school intends to hire a new math teacher, math department head, or math and science director. Do any professional mathematics or educational organizations such as the MAA, NCTM, or NAIS publish a list or summary of competencies, skills, and qualifications that schools should seek in such new hires?

Answer (score 8):

The MAA has a document (for undergraduate institutions) titled "Guidelines for Programs and Departments in Undergraduate Mathematical Sciences" and addresses some of this in Section C: "Program Faculty and Staffing". See http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/curriculum-department-guidelines-recommendations/guidelines-for-undergrad-programs#c